# Protect watermark text in html source code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to protect my watermark text in my html code. This is to differentiate between free users and paid user.

Eg: I have a watermark text as below

```
<footer>
    <div>
        Designed by Company Name 
    </div>
</footer>
```

Is there a way to prevent user from removing div tag from their source code?

Comment: Is this a theme/template that you're distributing to users? There's no way to make the HTML not editable if someone has the source or simply downloads the source from your site. You can make it more difficult to find, but it's always possible remove it.

Comment: Absolutely not. Anybody can inspect your code in their browser, target the div and hit the delete button. HTML is just as easily tinkered with as that. The only way to imprint an immovable watermark over a text is to render it on a canvas or embed it as PDF or something.

Comment: Do the opposite. Insert it with script when the API key for paid version isn't valid

Comment: and insert the name letter by letter, so ctrl + shift + f is pressed they cant find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the copyright text via JavaScript.

```
<script id="copyright">
  var footer = document.createElement('footer');
  footer.innerHTML = 'Designed by Company Name';
  document.body.appendChild(footer);
  document.getElementById('copyright').remove();
</script>
```

Note how the script is removed after running, so it is not visible in the developer tools.

Comment: man this is genius! this answer fits your name